# Insulate garage ceiling

Tags: insulation

I want to insulate the ceiling of my garage, to make the family room above it warmer. The problem is that the garage has a finished ceiling (no exposed beams), so how to I affix the insulation to the ceiling? It doesn't need to be pretty. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it's not insulated? Did you oversee the garage ceiling being finished?

Answer (score 2):

- Option A - Blow it in (if there's no insulation in place between ceiling and floor now.) Drill holes, stuff in hoses (or hire a professional insulation-blowing company who may be better at it that you will be - it's somewhat tricky.)
- Option B - rip it open, insulate, re-cover. Consider adding radiant floor heat tubing first.
- Option C - add sheet insulation, and more drywall over that. You do NOT want exposed plastic insulation on the ceiling of a garage that's below living space - that would constitute a huge fire hazard.